# convert mobile cmyk to hex

Tags: mobile, colors, hex, cmyk

I need to convert this string into a hex color: '0.047,0.380,0.247,0.900'.  It is labeled 'Forrest' and is sent to a mobile device to define a background color.  Presumably it is a cmyk color.

Anyone know of a good way to convert this using either php or js/jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This site](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/cmyk-rgb-and-php) should be able to help you a bit.  Just needs a bit of math.

**EDIT:**  Here's a better page: http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH

Comment: Hm, that seems to confirm the approach I had found earlier.  I'll look more closely at my input.  Thanks.

Comment: These formulas are posted all over the internet. But the results are so bad that they're not usable for anything slightly serious. You'll need to use a color profile for better results. It doesn't even need to be device-specific. You can try it on http://www.codecrete.net/cmyk.